# how to rotate a pie chart clockwise and anti-clockwise as in roambi app in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-plot

I had drawn the pie chart using core plot library. But the thing is I want to rotate the pie chart in clock wise and anti clockwise direction as in Roambi application.

Can anyone suggest me how can I do like this.

Anyone's help will be deeply appreciated.

Thank's all,
Monish.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(M_PI * 90 / 180.0)); // clockwise 
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(-M_PI * 90 / 180.0)); // anti-clockwise
```

Comment: http://chris-software.com/index.php/2009/04/26/animations-and-transformations/ check this

Comment: Thanks for the link, its very useful.Wt I am asking is how to setup the pan gesture for this circular rotation.

Comment: in the gestureRecognizer selector, implement the above methods

Comment: But how can I detect whethere I moved it in clockwise or anti- clockwise?

Comment: The link is broken, can you please submit another url to that article or edit your post as necessary pls? thank you